# Acción por voz dentro de un if/elif Python-3.x

Tags: python-3.x, condiciones

Estoy empezando de a poco con Python. En si estoy armando una aplicación que es parecido a Alexa, Jarvis, Cortana, entre otros en el aspecto de automatizar acciones mediante voz.

Versión de Python: Python 3.10.0

Estoy usando estas librerías:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import urllib.request
import json
import datetime
import wikipedia
```

Mi problema es que cuando le digo al "BOT" o aplicación para enviar un mensaje a "x" persona no reconoce la acción que debería de hacer, dejo mi código aquí

```py
    elif 'envia mensaje a' in rec:
        if 'papa' in rec:
            msj = rec.replace('mensaje a papa', '')
            talk('Enviando mensaje a papa...' + msj)
            print(papa, msj)
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(papa, msj, 20)
        elif 'mama' in rec:
            msj = rec.replace('mensaje a mama', '')
            talk('Enviando mensaje a mama...' + msj)
            print(mama, msj)
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(mama, msj, 20)
```

Las variables `mama` y `papa` tienen un numero asignado de cada uno.
La acción `pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly` manda un msj automáticamente por Whatsapp
La acción `msj = rec.replace('mensaje a xx', '')` remplaza el texto inicial en este caso "mensaje a mama" por un mensaje vacío para que el bot no repita eso. Solo envía lo que se ha dicho luego de la variable msj un ej: "Mensaje a mama" -> "Hola mama" <- esto envía el bot

En si el problema está en que no me reconoce cuando digo "Bot envía mensaje a xx o xx"

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: No he entendido bien. Sabes si se ejecuta algunos de los `print` puestos en el código??

Comment: Hola @Christian gracias por responder. Y no los ejecuta, por eso estoy tratando de que dentro de esos ELIF se ejecute la acción mediante voz, al decir mama o papa